# Extracting file from tarfile with only basename using Python

Tags: python, tarfile

I have a 'tafile' which contains files with complete path '/home/usr/path/to/file'. When I extract the file to the curent folder it creates the complete path recursively.
Is there a way that I can extract the file with only the base name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`TarFile.extractfile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extractfile) and write it into a file of your choice.

Comment: This is a solution but I would rather like to rename the file instead of copying each line.

Comment: You can't help but "copy each line", as that's how extracting is done. `shutil.copyfileobj` is a convenient tool to do the copying yourself.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the `arcnames` by hacking the `TarInfo` objects you get from `Tarfile.getmembers()`. Then you can use `Tarfile.extractall` to write the members to your chosen destination under their new names.

E.g., the following function will select members from an arbitrary subtree of the archive and extract them to a destination under their base names:

```
def extractTo(tar, dest, selector):
    if type(selector) is str:
        prefix = selector
        selector = lambda m: m.name.startswith(prefix)
    members = [m for m in tar.getmembers() if selector(m)]
    for m in members:
        m.name = os.path.basename(m.name)
    tar.extractall(path = dest, members = members)
```

Suppose `tar` is a `TarFile` instance representing an archive with some members in a `utilities/misc` directory, and you would like to fold those members into the `local/bin` directory. You could do:

```
extractTo(tar, 'local/bin', 'utilities/misc/')
```

Note the trailing `/` on the directory prefix. We don't want to add the `misc` directory to `local/bin', rather, just its members.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function`extractall` to fit your needs. According to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html?highlight=tarfile#module-tarfile) : 
*Extract all members from the archive to the current working directory or directory path.*

```
TarFile.extractall(path="my/path")
```

Comment: The 'tarfile' is not being created by me. Is there a way I can change the arcname after the tarfile is created?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's what I became aware after a more careful reading ! Please see my edit, it should fit your needs better.

Comment: It still creates the folders recursively, as in 'my/path//home/usr/path/to/file'.