# Extract a file and rename it at the same time in python

Tags: python, tarfile

I want to extract a file with a specific extension from my tarball file and at the same time give it a specific name. So far I can choose the file I want by extension and extract it. But how can I rename it the way I want?

```
tar = tarfile.open('files/compressed/compressed_file.tar.gz')
for member in tar.getmembers():
    if member.isfile() and member.name.endswith('.nii'):
        f = tar.extract(member, 'files/decompressed/')
    else:
        continue
tar.close()
```

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149457/extracting-file-from-tarfile-with-only-basename-using-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extractfile) of the method you're using, the file object returned is read only.  This means you will have to read in the data, then write it to another file just as you normally would.  As you re-write the file you can name it how you want:

```
lines = f.readlines()

with open("your_filename_here.nii", 'w') as output:
    for line in lines:
        output.write(line)
```

Depending on how your file is formatted you may need to tweak the template above.