# Tarfile/Zipfile extractall() changing filename of some files

Tags: python, file, zip, tar

Hello I am currently working on a tool that has to extract some .tar files.

It works great for the most part but I have one problem:

Some .tar and .zip files have names that include "illegal" characters (f.ex ":").
This program has to run on windows machines so I have to deal with this.

Is there a way I can change the name of some of the files in the extracted output if it contains a ":" or another illegal windows character.

My current implementation:

```
def read_zip(filepath, extractpath):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(filepath, 'r') as zfile:
        contains_bad_char = False
        for finfo in zfile.infolist():
            if ":" in finfo.filename:
                contains_bad_char = True
        if not contains_bad_char:
            zfile.extractall(path=extractpath)


def read_tar(filepath, extractpath):
    with tarfile.open(filepath, "r:gz") as tar:
        contains_bad_char = False
        for member in tar.getmembers():
            if ":" in member.name:
                contains_bad_char = True
        if not contains_bad_char:
            tar.extractall(path=extractpath)
```

So currently I am just ignoring these outputs all together, which is not ideal.

To describe better what I am asking for I can provide a small example:

```
file_with_files.tar -> small_file_1.txt
                    -> small_file_2.txt
                    -> annoying:file_1.txt
                    -> annoying:file_1.txt
```

Should extract to

```
file_with_files -> small_file_1.txt
                -> small_file_2.txt
                -> annoying_file_1.txt
                -> annoying_file_1.txt
```

Is the only solution to iterate over every fileobject in the compressed file and extract one by one or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: You need to use a library that allows you to provide a callback function that will replace each ':' by '_' on the fly. As an example, the Zip-Ada does it, see Compose_func @ http://unzip-ada.sf.net/za_html/unzip__ads.htm#85_8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [[Python.Docs]: ZipFile.extract(member, path=None, pwd=None)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extract):

> On Windows illegal characters (`:`, `<`, `>`, `|`, `"`, `?`, and `*`) replaced by underscore (`_`).

So, things are already taken care of:

> ```py
> >>> import os
> >>> import zipfile
> >>>
> >>> os.getcwd()
> 'e:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q055340013'
> >>> os.listdir()
> ['arch.zip']
> >>>
> >>> zf = zipfile.ZipFile("arch.zip")
> >>> zf.namelist()
> ['file0.txt', 'file:1.txt']
> >>> zf.extractall()
> >>> zf.close()
> >>>
> >>> os.listdir()
> ['arch.zip', 'file0.txt', 'file_1.txt']
> ```

A quick browse over *TarFile* (source and *doc*) didn't reveal anything similar (and I wouldn't be very surprised if there wasn't, as *.tar* format is mainly used on *Nix*), so you'd have to do it manually. Things aren't as simple as I expected, since *TarFile* doesn't offer the possibility of extracting a member under a different name, like *ZipFile* does. 
Anyway, here's a piece of code (I had *ZipFile* and *TarFile* as muses or sources of inspiration):

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os
import tarfile


def unpack_tar(filepath, extractpath=".", compression_flag="*"):
    win_illegal = ':<>|"?*'
    table = str.maketrans(win_illegal, '_' * len(win_illegal))
    with tarfile.open(filepath, "r:" + compression_flag) as tar:
        for member in tar.getmembers():
            #print(member, member.isdir(), member.name, member.path)
            #print(type(member))
            if member.isdir():
                os.makedirs(member.path.translate(table), exist_ok=True)
            else:
                with open(os.path.join(extractpath, member.path.translate(table)), "wb") as fout:
                    fout.write(tarfile.ExFileObject(tar, member).read())


def main(*argv):
    unpack_tar("arch00.tar")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

Note that the above code works for simple *.tar* files (with simple members, including directories).

Submitted [[Python.Bugs]: tarfile: handling Windows (path) illegal characters in archive member names](https://bugs.python.org/issue36534). 
I don't know what its outcome is going to be, since I submitted a couple of issues (and also fixes for them) that were more serious (on my *PoV*), but for various reasons, they were rejected.

Comment: Your implementation works well for simple files as stated. In the case where there is a .tar file that contains a folder with a name with illegal characters it does not work however. Since I did not state anything about such cases in my question I will mark this answer correct.

Comment: What about now?

Comment: yes it works much better, I like the use of member.isdir()!

Comment: You could simplify the code by using `tar.extractfile` + `shutil.copyfileobj`, see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/6149487

Comment: on the else statement, before creating the file, sometimes you have to create the folder else it will result in error

just add

`os.makedirs(pathlib.Path(extractpath).parent, exist_ok=True)`

Comment: @trycatch: thank you for the suggestion, I will look into it. As I specified somewhere, it's not designed to be robust :).

Comment: @trycatch: How did you encounter the error? In the archive members, a directory comes before any of its children. Maybe if a directory already exists?